# My question got removed

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/148721/is-it-socially-acceptable-to-poop-at-work-i-have-had-lifelong-digestive-issues) was removed. I didn't have any opportunity to clarify or defend myself because I just got home from work and saw it removed now. I posted it last night before going to bed. All the answers and comments were made during the day when I was not here.

Many comments and answers seem to imply that *of course* it is fine to poop at work, even ridiculing me and asking "why do I ask" etc. You can go see what they wrote.

It is baffling to me that users of workplaceSE are apparently so comfortable with pooping at work. I have always been told that it is not acceptable for women to poop at work (I am a woman, and this is one of the few situations where it does make a difference in the workplace). In a previous job, another woman developed a reputation as an "office pooper" and became a kind of pariah in our department.

In my current job, I know two women who don't eat at all during the work day so they can ensure they do not have to poop. The stigma is that great.

So no, my question is not "shitposting" although I appreciate the pun. It is a serious question about the social acceptability of pooping.

EDIT:

A quick google search of "pooping at work" reveals literally hundreds of articles about the subject, and here are some examples:

https://gawker.com/5839808/how-to-poop-at-work

https://www.bustle.com/articles/62656-7-reasons-why-every-woman-should-absolutely-poop-at-work

https://jezebel.com/the-real-way-to-poop-at-work-with-100-secrecy-5926790

https://thoughtcatalog.com/michael-podell/2013/11/i-poop-at-work-and-these-are-my-observations/

https://mashable.com/2016/12/21/tips-pooping-at-work/

https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/17/style/women-poop-at-work.html

https://www.womenshealthmag.com/health/a19907348/pooping-in-public/

So clearly, the answer here is not as obvious as "of course you can poop at work, that's what the bathrooms are for" - many of the articles I found state that you should not poop at work.

Comment: Answer to your question is, yes, that is why there are bathrooms at work because people need to take care of the downstairs business working there 8 hours a day. As to why that would be removed, because that sounds exactly like a shitpost

Comment: @VictorS If the question is answerable, then it is a fit for WorkplaceSE. Also, a quick google search of "pooping at work" reveals literally hundreds of articles about the subject, I added some examples to the OP. It's not such a trivial matter, especially for women, for whom it is socially unacceptable to poop at work (but still equally necessary as it is for men).

Comment: You didn't mention anything about it being gender related - that women are discouraged from pooping at work.  Although, as a woman, that is something I have never heard - that's on the level of the alleged Victorian idea that women don't fart.  Our bodies may have differences, but the digestive system is pretty much the same.  Perhaps if the question were more "I've been told that, as a woman, I shouldn't poop at work, so what are reasonable options?"  Although, the same answer "everyone poops" is the correct one.

Comment: Just a thought - in the interest of being helpful. Since you've googled and found hundreds of articles on this subject, perhaps you don't need a question any more after all? Sounds like you have plenty of reading.

Comment: https://smile.amazon.com/Everyone-Poops-Taro-Gomi/dp/B0014JDSPU/

Comment: @notmySOaccount, One more thing. "waiting in agony for a moment the bathroom is empty to unleash my turd." Do not wait until the bathroom is empty to do your business. Seriously, don't do that. Don't wait. Just do it. If you wait, you just make things weirder. And by that, I don't mean that you shouldn't take your time. By all means, take your time, but you know what I'm saying.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was one of the users who voted to delete - your question may have been genuine or it may not. But given it was written in a puerile way with unnecessary details and schoolyard descriptions of your defecation process and the consistency of your feces I figured the balance of probabilities were against it.

Clearly our remaining moderator agreed with me and your post was deleted.

We've had other questions that have touched on bathroom matters - and while I'm not suggesting they are duplicates they do offer pointers for how this subject can be approached in a mature and reasonable way.

Comment: I voted to close for the same reason. I would have voted to delete if I was able to.

Comment: A quick google search of "pooping at work" reveals literally hundreds of articles about the subject, I added some examples to the OP. Clearly this is not a trivial subject. People treating it as "no big deal" or as an unimportant question are missing the point. (Also, the details you mention were necessary to reflect the urgency of the bathroom needs to prevent responses telling me to wait until I get back home. This is the most common suggestion from people I know IRL. "Just wait until you get home." That's not possible.)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen the original, but can imagine that the issue was not with the substance but with the style. Workplace tends to be wary of "click-bait" posts and other types of content that can attract large groups of random people from network sites.

Reading what you have wrote here, **it seems like several different reasonable questions can be constructed**. Advice would be:

- keep it focused, i.e. pick a single topic
- keep it real-life, not hypothetical: "I heard from colleague that pooping in the office is a big no-no, what should I do?"
- keep it on-topic for this site: not asking "how can I get over fear of pooping in public" but rather "professional way to deal with [something]". We are not even interpersonal website